# How to open database connection in constructor using dbcontext in derived class(ASP.Net MVC with entity framework)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Is there anyway to open database connection automatically using constructor. Currenntly, 
i am passing connection string in constructor.

```
public class RezNextETLAdapter:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PropertyInfo> PropertyInfos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoomInfo> RoomInfos { get; set; }

    public RezNextETLAdapter()
        : base("name=PmsDatabase")
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyInfo>().ToTable("PR002TBL");
        modelBuilder.Entity<RoomInfo>().ToTable("PR003TBL");
        modelBuilder.Entity<RoomInfo>().ToTable("FMHCHTBL");
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {

    }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to open underlying connection...

```
public RezNextETLAdapter()
    : base("name=PmsDatabase")
{
     ObjectContext.Connection.Open();

}

public ObjectContext ObjectContext
{
    get { return ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext; }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for your quick help. I tried the same but no luck....after opening the connecting the connection its not coming out from the constructor method and getting the inner exception as "The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string". Any update for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use your db class **without connection**

```
public class RezNextETLAdapter:DbContext
{
  ...
}
```

And in web.config your connection string should be like this:

```
<add name="RezNextETLAdapter" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\; Initial Catalog=RezNextETLAdapter; Integrated Security=true;" />
```

Comment: Hi Bey, Thanks for your quick help. Could you please explain me how it will open the database connection with the class name? Sorry, i am begineer to entity framework and wants to know about this in detail......